# I've disabled periodic checks for updates. Why does it still do so?

Tags: 12.04, updates

I use Ubuntu 12.04.1 64bit.
I always used my update settings set to "never check" and then manually check for updates when I need to.
But the last week or so I saw that Ubuntu started checking for updates automatically every day. I went to the settings but is was still set to "never check".

So I changed it to "every two days" to see if that will help.
Now it check 2 to three times per day automatically.

Why is it ignoring my update settings and automatically checks so randomly every day ?

Edit: Did the following with the help of gertvdijk:

On request checked if I have unattended-upgrades installed and I have.
Used suggested command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` to configure it to not do automatic updates.
Proceeded to check file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` for the following settings:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

and all is at zero after the configuration above.

Will monitor and provide feedback if this resolved the problem.

edit 2:

None of the above worked. My system just informed me of updates that is available , so it still is automatically checking.

Comment: What exactly makes you believe it's *checking* for updates rather than just *notifying* you about it? If it already has fetched a new list of packages from the repository with updates ready (compared to your system state) it will keep informing you that updates are available, but it doesn't have to *check* again for that.

Comment: No it's not that. I know because every time there is different updates and I do install them. Then later in the day there will be some more different updates again. This is how I know it is checking for updates.

Comment: There certainly is *something else* on your machine running an APT-update command (reading your [other comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240324/why-is-ubuntu-ignoring-my-update-settings#comment299730_240333))! Did you install other package manager or desktop environments, e.g. KDE? They may come with their own update managers (just a GUI in front of the same APT). And do you have the package `unattended-upgrades` installed by coincidence?

Comment: I don't have any other DE's and the only other package manager I have installed is Synaptec but that works of the same settings. I do have that package you mentioned. I checked and saw it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be (for example) if you are adding a PPA and run "sudo apt-get update" you will be manually checking the repositories for any updated indexes.  Update manager will then use this information and let you know if there are any updates.

Comment: Nope this is not the reason. I didn't run the update command

Answer (score 0):

Try reconfiguring `unattended-upgrades`:

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` in a terminal which allows you to easily reconfigure its behaviour. Answer the first question with 'No'.

To be really sure, check the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` for the `Update-Package-Lists` to be disabled:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

I suggest you go to [Ubuntu wiki: AutomaticSecurityUpdates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) for more details on the configuration for that package.

Comment: I'm gonna remove it (never installed it anyway, must have been something else that added it) and will give feedback in few days if that was the problem. Thank you

Comment: Oh boy no , removing it is not an option. When I mark that for removal then the system wants to remove a whole lot of other system packages as well. I instead went for your second suggestion. A very simple yes or no and I selected no. Will see what happens now for a few days.

Comment: @Mazal Yeah, it seems installed with every `-desktop` task nowadays. For me it's installed as well (surprised), but configured to do nothing at all. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok I checked that file on my side and it is all at zeros , guess due to that config I did. I'm just very confused as to why it only started the last week or so. Been using this install for about 6 months without this happening.

Comment: gertvdijk , ok I made some edits in the question. Is it ok like that ?

Comment: @Mazal Yup, sounds like a good question now - I'm lost about why it happens now. +1'd it :) I'll leave my answer here for future reference (other visitors bumping into the same/similar) or for when it seemed related later.

Comment: @ gertvdijk, it didn't work. The system just showed me there is updates available. So it still is checking automatically.